# Geary Mail in Elementary OS only working for Gmail account

Tags: linux, email, gmail

I have been running Elementary OS for a while now and believe it or not; I have only just yesterday, decided to setup my emails in theGeary mail client.

I've successfully setup 6 email accounts in Geary, however, the only one that works is the Gmail one. I don't really even need the Gmail one.

The other 5 accounts are for my business email and other (personal) accounts. I have done this a billion times and I know that my server details were entered correctly.

Geary Mail does list all the different accounts I've added, but when I expand all their folders, the only one that has Inbox/Sent/Junk/Deleted folders is the Gmail one.

How can I get Geary to work?